# React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state

i'm new in react native and i have an error i can't understand, the console sends a message that says

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function

My code is the next

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

const LoginStack = () => {

    const initialLoginState = {
        isLoading: true,
        userName: null,
        userToken: null,
    };

    const loginReducer = (prevState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN':
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    userToken: action.token,
                    isLoading: false,
                };
            case 'LOGIN':
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    userName: action.id,
                    userToken: action.token,
                    isLoading: false,
                };  
            case 'LOGOUT':
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    userName: null,
                    userToken: null,
                    isLoading: false,
                };
        }
    };
    
    const [loginState, dispatch] = useReducer(loginReducer, initialLoginState);

    const authContext = useMemo(() => ({
        signIn: (userName, password) => {
            let userToken;
            userName = null;
            if ( userName == 'user' && password == 'pass' ) {
                userToken: 'irais';
            }
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', id: userName, token: userToken });
        },
        signOut: () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' });
        },
    }));

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // setIsLoading(false)
            dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN', token: 'irais' });
        },1000);
    }, []); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is 'useEffect'. You need to return a clean up function to make sure that any effects are disposed of properly.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setTimeout(() => {
            // setIsLoading(false)
            dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN', token: 'irais' });
        },1000);
        
        return () => clearTimeout(handle);
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `useEffect`.
It schedules an async task (timeout) which updates the component state (using `dispatch`).
Then, it is possible that your component already mounted when this timeout fullfils.
The solution is to use a cleanup function, which is basically the return statement of `useEffect`:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            // setIsLoading(false)
            dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN', token: 'irais' });
        },1000);

        return () => {
           clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    }, []);
```